# Finding average cost from C(x) - Calculus

Tags: calculus

I am given C(x) = 2^x and I need to find average cost. Can anyone solve this. I believe you divide 2^x by x but I am not sure what that result would be.

Much appreciated!

Average Cost = (there is a line over this C) C(x) = C(x)/x

Comment: yes. all i am given is C(x) = 2^x and the question is Find the equation for average cost.

Comment: It is probably $C'(x) = 2^x\ln(2)$

Answer (score 2):

Average cost = AC = $\dfrac{2^x}{x}$.

If you are looking for minimum AC, we take the derivative and set it equal to zero, so we have:

$$AC' = \dfrac{2^x (x \ln 2 -1)}{x^2} = 0$$

So, we have:

$$2^x (x \ln 2 -1) = 0 \rightarrow x = \dfrac{1}{\ln 2}$$

Comment: Gets a TU from me! +1 Hope you're having a wonderful day!

Comment: Happy POETs Day! ;-)

Comment: Yes, you are spoiled! :-P